# Alternate proof of Archimedean property for integers (Burton)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm working through Burton's Number Theory and the Archimedean property for $\mathbb{Z}^+$ is proved as

Theorem: If $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, there exists $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $na \geq b$.

Proof: Assume that the statement of the theorem is not true, so that for some $a$ and $b$, $na < b$ for every positive integer $n$. Then the set $ = \{ −  \mid  \in \mathbb{Z}^+\}$ consists entirely of positive integers. By the well-ordering principle, $S$ will possess a least element, say, $b - ma$. Notice that $b - (m + 1)a$ also lies in $S$, because $S$ contains all integers of this form. Furthermore, we have $b − (m + 1)a = (b − ma) − a < b - ma$ contrary to the choice of $b - ma$ as the smallest integer in $S$. This contradiction arose out of our original assumption that the Archimedean property did not hold; hence, this property is proven true.

I'm wondering if the following qualifies as an alternate direct proof.

Proof:

Let $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ be two positive integers. We have two cases.

If $a \geq b$, let $n = 1$ and observe that $na = a \geq b$.

If $a < b$, let $n = b$ and observe that $na = ba \geq b$ (since $a$ is a positive integer). QED.

In particular, are my assumptions about integer ordering appropriate in this context?

Answer (score 1):

Dislaimer:- I can't comment so I am posting this as an answer.

You can just choose n=b in every case. The point of the proof present in Burton's book is to prove the Archimedean property from the most basic principles possible, i.e. without making too many assumptions.

For example, this could be considered nitpicking, but you assumed that $ba \geq b$ for all $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ while Burton's proof doesn't.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!